# Copy paste the filtered offset value in different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The paste value shows as "TRUE" in Range("H1"). Could you help me fix this.

```
Sub SelectFirstFilteredRow()

Dim ws As Worksheet, MyRange As Range

Set wsD = Sheets("OB")

Set sh2 = Worksheets("LPN")

wsD.Select

wsD.Cells(1, 3).Select

ActiveCell.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="ASINS IN INBOUND", Operator:=xlFilterValues

ActiveCell.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="AU", Operator:=xlFilterValues

wsD.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3).Select

Cells(1, 3).Offset(1).Resize(6).Copy

sh2.Range("H2") = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 3).Offset(1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: `sh2.Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`, or just `Cells(1, 3).Offset(1).Resize(6).Copy sh2.Range("H2")` and get rid of the last line.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response